# Very different (and wrong) values from two pressure sensors

Tags: sensor, i2c, pressure

I connected these two sensors on two different I2C busses on my board:

- ABP2LANT001PG2A3XX
- ABP2LANT060PG2A3XX

Here the datasheet of the [ABP2 Series](https://prod-edam.honeywell.com/content/dam/honeywell-edam/sps/siot/it-it/products/sensors/pressure-sensors/board-mount-pressure-sensors/basic-abp2-series/documents/sps-siot-abp2-series-datasheet-32350268-en.pdf).
To begin, I printed out the 7 byte returned from both sensors after issuing the measurement command (`0xAA 0x00 0x00`):

Here an example of a reading:

```
Sensor 1: 40 1A 16 CA 4F 5B 58 
Sensor 2: 40 1A DA 25 80 09 07
```

According to the datasheet, the first byte is the status register and the value `0x40` is consistent (device powered, no errors, valid data - since I waited 10 ms before reading the values). To be sure I'm reading correctly the data, I removed the delay and I get `0x60`.

My first concern is about the temperature values: both sensors are close to each other at room temperature (about 20 °C). But the returned values are *very* different:

- Sensor 1: `0x4F5B58` = 5200728
- Sensor 2: `0x800907` = 8390919

Converting them to a temperature they mean:

- Sensor 1: 5200728 * 200 / 16777215 - 50 = 12.00 °C
- Sensor 2: 8390919 * 200 / 16777215 − 50 = 50.03 °C

Both of them differs from each other and are both wrong.
Is there anything I'm missing looking at the datasheet?

For completeness here my test code:

```
uint8_t data[7];
uint8_t cmd[3] = {0xAA, 0x00, 0x00};
Wire.beginTransmission(0x28);
Wire.write(cmd, 3); 
Wire.endTransmission();
delay(10);
Wire.requestFrom(0x28, 7);

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    data[i] = Wire->read();
    Serial.printf("%02X ", data[i]);
}
```

I also checked the returned values of `write()` (it's 3 and it's ok) and `endTransmission()` (it's 0 and it's ok). Also `requestFrom` returns 7 and should be ok as well. So it seems there are no error on the bus.

Comment: Connect sensor 1 to I2C2 and sensor 2 to I2C1 and see what happens.

Comment: @Zelig63 done. The values follow the sensors.

Comment: I don't see any spec on the accuracy of the temperature sensor. It may simply be poorly calibrated.

Comment: @JohnDoty it's specified in Table 2: ±5 °C

Comment: Are the pressure readings consistent with each other? Are the temperature readings consistent over successive readings and do they vary if you warm them up?

Comment: @DamienD I cannot say if the pressure readings are accurate since I have no pressure on input ports. But all the readings are quite stable (i.e. < 0.01 psi) after conversion

Comment: @Mark if you make a graph of the numbers returned for the temperature, does it look plausible (varying slowly if you warm/cool them) or is it random noise / unchanging?

Comment: Have the two sensors been soldered to your board?  I've seen issues where reflow ovens have reflowed sensor internals and damaged them. Try one with clip leads.

Comment: @DamienD I'll try it tomorrow

Comment: Take a close look to be sure that you have the sensor you expect to have.  I once had questions for Honeywell with respect to a similar product as the external markings did not jive.  It took them looking up the batch code to confirm the markings were, well, not informative.

Comment: @Aaron, no they are not soldered to the PCB

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen on one of them is reported the expected p/n, on the other there is nothing

Comment: Also note that the pressure result is good for 14 bits (out of the 24 you get in the response).  Datasheet page 4.  Not sure about the temp, other than the range (note 8) is -40 to 125C.

Comment: I suppose it's time to apply a logic analyzer to the bus, and post what you see for a response.  At least we'll have more to look at...